# Install private gitlab repo from docker via deploy token in the requirements.txt

Tags: docker, gitlab, requirements.txt

I saw a docker container in which the Dockerfile reads

```
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt
```

and where the requirements.txt reads (modified for anonymisation)

```
git+https://gitlab+deploy-token-123456:a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8j9@gitlab.com/example/lib.git@a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8j9k1l2m3n4o5p6q7r8s9t#egg=other_example
```

Now I want to do this (install a private git repo) myself, but am struggling on finding any information on how to create this link to put in the `requirements.txt`.
I managed to create this `gitlab+deploy-token-123456`, and the part behind the `@` is probably the commit SHA, but I don't know how to get the port (part behind the `:`, I assume it's the port?).
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8j9` is the security token for `gitlab+deploy-token-123456`.

If you've created a deploy token, it should haven given you the security token, eg the format is:

```
git clone https://<username>:<deploy_token>@gitlab.example.com/tanuki/awesome_project.git
```

from [deploy token usage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#usage).